# Resolve incompatible packages for a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, pip, jinja2, werkzeug

Here's my requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.6
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.3
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.0
click==8.1.7
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
greenlet==3.0.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
multidict==6.0.4
openai==0.28.1
psycopg2==2.9.9
python-dotenv==1.0.0
requests==2.31.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.21
tqdm==4.66.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==2.0.6
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yarl==1.9.2
```

I'm playing whack-a-mole between Flask, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, and Flask-SQLAlchemy versions. The application seemed to work previously. However, I didn't keep a clean list of deployed packages, and I kept experimenting with various installs without ever checking a "clean deployment."

There must be a better way to figure this out. Please help!

Issues I've run into:

1. ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' => reinstalled flask, jinja2
2. ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' => reinstalled flask-sqlalchemy and flask
3. ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls' => can't figure out the compatibility between the three

Comment: Use a newer version of Flask that doesn't rely on jinja2's escape (which is long since gone). Try removing all the version numbers from your requirements.txt, then pip install it and let pip figure out compatible versions...

Comment: I appreciate the response, and have tried that before... my first requirements.txt was simple and without any version numbers (i.e. Flask, Flask-Login, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Jinja2, openai, psycopg2, python-dotenv).

However, for some reason, the application worked fine locally, and on Heroku. When I migrated from Heroku to Azure App Services, the app build failed due to incompatibility issues. So I redeployed locally to test what was going on, and that's where I ran into the first: ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls'

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the generous comments, and a a lot of trial and error, I was able to converge to a requirements.txt that worked both during application deployment and at runtime.

```
Werkzeug==2.3.0
Flask
Flask-Login
Flask-SQLAlchemy
Jinja2
openai
psycopg2
python-dotenv
SQLAlchemy==1.4.15
```